# Display HashMap data in JSF page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hashmap, el

I am struggling in displaying the content of hashmap in primefaces widgets like inputtext, selectonemenu etc etc.

I have defined hasmaps

```
  private Map<String, String> subIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  private Map<String, Map<String, String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

> // their getter and setters.

*SubIdMap contains the keys and values*

**for id 001**

```
private Map<String, String> subIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
subIdMap.put("id", "001");
subIdMap.put("name", "Alexender");
subIdMap.put("age", "24");
subIdMap.put("sex", "Male");
subIdMap.put("country", "Greece");
```

**for id = 002**

```
private Map<String, String> subIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

subIdMap.put("id", "002");
subIdMap.put("name", "John");
subIdMap.put("age", "25");
subIdMap.put("sex", "Male");
subIdMap.put("country", "US");
```

dataMap is a map which has ID's as keys and subIdMap as their values

```
 private Map<String, Map<String, String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

dataMap.put("001", subIdMap);
or
dataMap.put("002", subIdMap);
```

I have a page where if a user clicks on id 001, it will get the data for id =001 or for id =002 from bean and display in the xhtml page and . i am not able to show data from Map in the fields in xhtml page

**snippet**

```
  @ManagedBean(name = "sampleBean")
    @ViewScoped
    public class SampleBean implements Serializable{

    private Map<String, String> subIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
     private Map<String, Map<String, String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

public SampleBean() {

subIdMap.put("id", "001");
subIdMap.put("name", "Alexender");
subIdMap.put("age", "24");
subIdMap.put("sex", "Male");
subIdMap.put("country", "Greece");

dataMap.put("001",subIdMap);

    }


    /**
         * @return the subIdMap
         */
        public Map<String, String> getSubIdMap() {
            return subIdMap;
        }

        /**
         * @param subIdMap the subIdMap to set
         */
        public void setSubIdMap(Map<String, String> subIdMap) {
            this.subIdMap = subIdMap;
        }

    /**
         * @return the dataMap
         */
        public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getDataMap() {
            return dataMap;
        }

        /**
         * @param dataMap the dataMap to set
         */
        public void setDataMap(Map<String, Map<String, String>> dataMap) {
            this.dataMap = dataMap;
        }

    }
```

**xhtml page**

```
<p:inputText id="textId" value="............." />

<p:selectOneMenu id="selectId" value="................" />
```

I need some directions here.

Comment: refer this it may help you http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/pprSelect.jsf

Comment: I recommend you to run through [DAO tutorial - the data layer](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html).

Answer (score 3):

To resolve your issue, add a get method in your bean to get KeySet from map like

```
 public List getKeyList() {
        return new ArrayList(dataMap.keySet());
 }
```

Then put repeat tag in jsf page to iterate and display the keys

```
<ui:repeat value="#{newJSFManagedBean.keyList}" var="key">
            Key : <h:outputText value="#{key}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

But instead of using map within map, I would suggest to create a simple class named `Person` and keep values there, then simply use a map like

```
private Map<String, Person> dataMap = new HashMap();
```

Hope you can proceed.

Comment: Just don't use maps at all. [DAO tutorial - the data layer](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Comment: Sure he can. There are a bunch of post with such solutions. I meant he should not use Maps for such purposes, like entity lookup. I think this is the wrong way and maybe you should mention that in your post like kolossus did below. A map of map for entities...

Comment: how to print both value and Key at time @vels4j

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with it in regular el as in

```
  value = "#{yourBean.map.firstKey.nestedKey}"
```

But I must say your design not recommended. At all. A map of a map for every entity? Your job will be a whole lot simpler if you just encapsulated all that data in a single class.